# Groupby / sort_values in looking at medical data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, group-by, chi-squared

> Hi - I'm a veterinarian and I am trying to look at some medical data
> in a dataframe. The df consists of 100k rows(!) , and amongst them
> some columns named 'ClinicName', 'Induction Agent', and 'Complication
> Present' (1 = True and 0 = false). example below:

[10 row example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMg0I.png)

| ClinicName | Induction Agent | Complication Present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Redhill | Propofol | 1 |
| Christchurch | Alfaxan | 0 |
| Redhill | Propofol | 1 |
| Worcester | Propofol | 0 |
| Christchurch | Alfaxan | 0 |
| Derby | Propofol | 0 |
| Worcester | Alfaxan | 1 |
| Derby | Propofol | 0 |
| Redhill | Propofol | 1 |

> I want to create a normalised horizontal bar graph showing whether a
> complication was present or not for each ClinicName and sub grouped by
> the type of induction agent. This I have successfully done this in the form :

```
complication_by_clinic = df.groupby(['ClinicName', 'Induction Agent'])['Complication Present'].
value_counts(normalize=False, sort=True, ascending=True,bins=None, dropna=True).unstack().tail(10)

complication_by_clinic.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=[20,5], colormap='winter')
```

> However what I really need is to sort_values so that the normalised values are ordered either ascending or descending, and that the induction agents in the bar graph are coloured differently from each other. Then I want to be able to remove all clinics data with an normalised value of less than a certain amount (say 0.1) by using df.drop.

> (To give some background  the reason is that on Chi squared analysis at the moment the values for induction agent and Complication Present of 0 are significantly skewing the data since some clinics are not entering data regularly)

> Something like this for sorting the values is needed but I can't get it right:

```
complication_by_clinic = df.sort_values(df.groupby(['ClinicName', 'Induction Agent'])['Complication Present'].sum()
```

But I'm also stuck on colouring the 'Induction Agent' in the bar graph differently. Any help much appreciated - and in return feel free to ask me a question about your pet!

This prtscr link shows how it is displayed at the moment:
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZB8F.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMg0I.png)
This is how I want it to look:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajl7cdyxWsko6Qu6lZZDEVcHgDaa?e=3sShAK

[Here are some additional print screens that may help

https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ajl7cdyxWsko6QxSYdylu-3CoC6H?e=hR1BfS  ]

Comment: Can you explain ` colouring the 'Induction Agent' in the bar graph differently` ?
I don't get it what do you want can you shareplot image and explain

Comment: can you sort me out a frenchy! I think you're close - if you have the relevant libs imported `df.groupby(['ClinicName', 'Induction Agent'])['Complication Present'].sum().plot(kind='bar')` could work could you create a sample of what you want? a simple example/drawing is fine

Comment: Thanks so much for your interest  Here's a link showing how I'd like the date to look

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajl7cdyxWsko6Qu6lZZDEVcHgDaa?e=3sShAK

> Thank you so much for your time..!

Comment: > Pygirl > I've also updated the body of the message with more information and the bar graph as currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st part:

```
complication_by_clinic.sort_values(['ClinicName', 'Induction Agent'], ascending=True).plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=[20,5], colormap='winter')
```

**Edit:**

Sorry it should be:

```
complication_by_clinic['sum'] = complication_by_clinic.sum(1)
complication_by_clinic.sort_values(by='sum', ascending=True).drop('sum', axis=1).plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=[20,5], colormap='winter')
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll give that a go

Comment: Thank you very much.. it's close , I think I be able to get there from what you've posted above